# How to create a brightness slider in UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I want to create a slider that can adjust the brightness of a game in Unreal Engine 4, but I don't know which module to use in blueprints to adjust brightness. Which blueprint module should I attach to the module for the slider's value change? Should this even be done in blueprints, or should I do it in C++ instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a post-process actor, and change its brightness value via blueprint